# RegEx: Match everything up to the last space without including it

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'd like to match everything in a string up to the last space but without including it. For the sake of example, I would like to match characters I put in **bold**:

```
RENATA T. GROCHAL
```

So far I have [`^(.+\s)(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gM3aM2/1) However, it matches the last space and I don't want it to. RegEx should work also for other languages than English, as mine does.

**EDIT:** I didn't mention that the second capturing group should not contain a space – it should be `GROCHAL` not `GROCHAL` with a space before it.

**EDIT 2:** My new RegEx based on what the two answers have provided is: [`^((.+)(?=\s))\s(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gM3aM2/2) and the RegEx used to replace the matches is `\3, \1`. It does the expected result:

```
GROCHAL, RENATa T.
```

Any improvements would be desirable.

Comment: How about matching `\S+` non-whitespaces before `$` end: [`(.+)\s(\S+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/kS5pF8/1) and replace with `$2, $1` similar @medvedev1088 solution with two groups `^(.+)\s(.+)`

Comment: @bobblebubble To me, your solution is much better than mine.

Comment: I voted for medvedev1088's solution as my idea is very similar.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks. I also incorporated your idea in my response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^(.+)\s(.+)`

with substitution string:

`\2, \1`

**Update:**

Another version that can collapse extra spaces between the 2 capturing groups:

[`^(.+?)\s+(\S+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/gM3aM2/3)

Comment: y'd rather explain why he has to try it, and why it may solve his problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use a positive lookahead assertion:

```
^(.+)(?=\s)
```

Capturing group 1 will contain the match.

Answer (score -1):

I like using named capturing groups:

```
rawName = RENATA T. GROCHAL
RegexMatch(rawName, "O)^(?P<firstName>.+)\s(?P<lastName>.+)", match)
MsgBox, % match.lastName ", " match.firstName
```