# Regex extracting string up until Whitespace followed by parenthesis OR extract everything

Tags: regex

I am extracting names without the parenthesis (and without the leading whitespace before it).

The problem is, that my regexes will fail either on the Whitespace before the parenthesis or on the condition that no parenthesis has been found.

**Here are the strings:**

```
Innere Stadt (Wien)
Leopoldstadt
Landstraße (Wien)
Wieden (Wien)
Margareten
Mariahilf
Neubau (Wien)
Josefstadt (Wien)
Alsergrund
Favoriten
Simmering
Meidling
Hietzing
Penzing (Wien)
Rudolfsheim-Fünfhaus
Ottakring
Hernals
Währing
Döbling
Brigittenau
Floridsdorf
Donaustadt
Liesing (Wien)
```

**My solutions**

Regex extracting also the Whitespace:

```
^[^\(]+
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/6m7hqS/1)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247497/regex-match-everything-up-to-the-last-space-without-including-it) led me to the following regex:

```
^(.+)\s\(
```

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/inAoQ8/1)

This is failing on the entries without the paranthesis though.

Comment: Try [`^[^\(]+(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/6m7hqS/3) or [`^[^\(]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/6m7hqS/2)

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew. So I basically had to add a condition after the character exception group to not get any whitespace. I tried to put include this condition in the brackets, which obviously wouldn't work out.

They both work!

Comment: I posted them both with explanations.

Comment: Both work in this case. But the the version with \b is to prefer because it wouldn't exclude the trailing whitespace even if it there is no opening parenthesis

Comment: Yes, I also mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry I initially didn't load the answer and didn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^(]+(?!\S)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6m7hqS/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^(]+` - 1 or more chars other than `(`, as many as possible
- `(?!\S)` - a location that is not immediately followed with a non-whitespace char (there must be a whitespace char or end of string)

Alternatively, you may use

```
^[^(]+\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6m7hqS/2).

Instead of the lookahead, there is a `\b`, a word boundary. This solution will return no trailing whitespaces if there are more than one before `(` (unlike the first pattern).